# How to load an array from soap and display on table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I tried load array from soap and display member of array on tableview.
When run I get this error:

```
App[711:c07] Log Output:(null)
2013-06-05 13:18:58.198 App[711:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1736012 0x1443e7e 0x16e9b6a 0x16e9a20 0x3a511 0xf23760 0x1c91685 0x1c934e5 0x1c92f07 0xf21e02 0x3a333 0xf49589 0xf47652 0xf4889a 0xf4760d 0xf47785 0xe94a68 0x223b911 0x223abb3 0x2278cda 0x16d88fd 0x227935c 0x22792d5 0x2163250 0x16b9f3f 0x16b996f 0x16dc734 0x16dbf44 0x16dbe1b 0x27977e3 0x2797668 0x387ffc 0x2add 0x2a05 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

My array : `NSMutableArray *BranchesNameArray;`

Calling SOAP here

```
NSString *mensagemSOAP= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<GetBranches xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<dt1>Africa</dt1>\n"
                         "</GetBranches>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"];

NSLog(@"SOAP Msg = \n%@\n\n", mensagemSOAP);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://servis.com:1249/service.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];    NSString *tamanhoMensagem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mensagemSOAP length]];

[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/GetBranches" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue:tamanhoMensagem forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[mensagemSOAP dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *conexao = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(conexao){
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
}else{
    NSLog(@"Connection Error.");
}


 }
```

didStart is here

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


 if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"branchname"] ) {

 NSLog(@"Log Output%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"]);
 [BranchesNameArray addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"]];


teveRetorno = YES;


 }
```

didEnd is here

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:   
  (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"branchname"] ) {

 [[self tableView]reloadData];

 teveRetorno = NO;

 }
 }
```

Table View is here

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
 if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text =[BranchesNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Before adding an object to array put a check if the object is a valid one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problum is you are add-object as Nil value that's why you getting error, So before you add Dictionary keyVlaue you have to check it is nil or not like bellow example may be useful for you and it helps you.

```
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


     if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"branchname"] ) {

          NSLog(@"Log Output%@",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"]);
          NSString *strValue= [attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"];

          if(strValue != (NSString*)[NSNull null])
          {
             [BranchesNameArray addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"]];
          } 
          else
          {

          }

          teveRetorno = YES;


 }

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:   
  (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
  if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"branchname"] ) {
 NSLog(@"Log array%@",BranchesNameArray);
 [[self tableView]reloadData];

 teveRetorno = NO;

  }
 }
```

Now you can load your array into your table view using bellow method:-

```
#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.BranchesNameArray count];


}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
-- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
 if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text =[BranchesNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 return cell;
 }
```

**NOTE**

**Do not forget to allocate your `BranchesNameArray` while your soap Method calling**

Comment: Thank you so much but   Log Output(null) Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: remove NSlog there is no need it

Comment: I removed log but it give same error friend.When table view open application stop and crash

Comment: I dont understand where is my mistake ? Array can not load from soap

Comment: yuor arra contain Null value so that the prob

Comment: put beack point at `didStartElement` and also NSlog your array befor load tableview reload  NSLog(@"Log Output%@",BranchesNameArray);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31253/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-mehmet-akyel)

Answer (score 1):

```
 [BranchesNameArray addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"]];
```

You cannot add null to array please make sure the value added is not null

```
if([attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"])
{
     [BranchesNameArray addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"branchname"]];
}
```

Edit Allocate first your array as

```
NSMutableArray *BranchesNameArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
```

Comment: One can add instance of NSNull to array, to remove the ambiguity you can say nil.

Comment: branchname is not null value.I can see in other log

Comment: @MehmetAkyel initialise array at beginning as in the answer.Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Before parsing the array check whether array count is >0

like

```
if([BranchesNameArray count] >0){
//do your operation
}
```

Comment: OK.I checked my array it is null.How I load my array with my codes ?